# Linear Operator , visual meaning.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Could someone give me the visual intuition, if there is any, of a Linear Operator $L$ ?

Given the definition that $L$ is linear if:

${L(f+g)=Lf+Lg}$    (with f and g being functions)

and

${L(tf)=tL(f)}$  (with t being scalar)

Comment: What do you mean by "visual meaning" ?

Comment: Like a visual intuition, if I have an image on a graph and apply a linear operator to it, how does it changes and in which way?

Comment: Go in the plane and see what happens there. It can be a rotation, dilation, shearing, reflection or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Operator* is a name for a special kind of *function*. Recall that in a geometric context functions are called maps: sloppily speaking a map sends points to points. Not all maps are linear, take a translation, e.g.

Now an *operator* is a function whose domain are functions itself: usually it sends functions to functions.  Not all operators are linear, but  the  example of the *differential operator* R.Burton gave is linear.  The term "Linear Operator" is often used as a name for linear mappings between infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

To make another example: Let $V:=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ the vector space of all real-valued sequences.  Then define the linear operator $S\colon V\to V$, defined by $S\bigl((a_1, a_2,a_3,\dotsc)\bigr)=(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dotsc)$.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article on [linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) has a pretty good animation. Outside of the elementary example, the next easiest case would probably be the differential operator $D(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. I would recommend using Desmos or GeoGebra to play with different functions and see how they behave under the action of different operators. It's a bit more specific, but you could also check out 3blue1brown's video on [group theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ).